# Golang, Ошибка "Build constraints exclude all Go files in '/home/vadim/go/src/github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk'"

Tags: golang, linux-mint

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не могу понять в чем ошибка. На просторах интернета много обсуждений данной проблемы, но конкретики не смог найти. Код взят из интернета. Импорт подчеркнут красным.

Язык Go, Linus Mint

```
package main
    import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk"
)

func main() {
    // Инициализируем GTK.
    gtk.Init(nil)

    // Создаём окно верхнего уровня, устанавливаем заголовок
    // И соединяем с сигналом "destroy" чтобы можно было закрыть
    // приложение при закрытии окна
    win, err := gtk.WindowNew(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Не удалось создать окно:", err)
    }
    win.SetTitle("Простой пример")
    win.Connect("destroy", func() {
        gtk.MainQuit()
    })

    // Создаём новую метку чтобы показать её в окне
    l, err := gtk.LabelNew("Привет, gotk3!")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Не удалось создать метку:", err)
    }

    // Добавляем метку в окно
    win.Add(l)

    // Устанавливаем размер окна по умолчанию
    win.SetDefaultSize(800, 600)

    // Отображаем все виджеты в окне
    win.ShowAll()

    // Выполняем главный цикл GTK (для отрисовки). Он остановится когда
    // выполнится gtk.MainQuit()
    gtk.Main()
}
```

Выдает ошибку - `"Build constraints exclude all Go files in '/home/vadim/go/src/github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk"`
Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: это точно весь код и больше ничего нет? как вы билдите? пожете отредактировать вопрос и добавить команду и весь вывод команды?

Comment: Код ниже, не принципиально. "github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk"-подчеркнуто красным и выдает упомянутую ошибку. Еще до билда. IDE-IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: это принципиально. так как без использования методов это будет "импорт не используется" и IDE будет ругаться. а код не будет собираться. а если указать `import _ "github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk"` то собирается без проблем. теперь проблема как это воспроизводить.

Comment: Изменил вопрос. Добавил весь код

Comment: _ "github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk" если так сделать, ничего не происходит.

Comment: установил gotk3, запустил `go build -o ./app ./main.go` - все скомпилировалось успешно. запускается тоже успешно.  у меня стоит `go version go1.15 darwin/amd64`. попробуйте скомпилировать в другом окружении, например docker

Comment: Все работает, как ни странно, но посмотрите на снимок-все красное. И при этом работает((()))

Comment: видно, что вы не добавили либу в go.mod. добавьте туда, после этого IDE не будет ругаться

Comment: В go.mod либа прописана автоматически, но все красное

Comment: Сталкивался с такой проблемой. Если нормально билдится, то скорей всего проблема с IDE. В большинстве случаев помогал перезапуск IDE, но можно попробовать удалить файлы go.mod и go.sum, так же удалить все в папке go_home/pkg создать новый модуль и выполнить команду go mod tidy. Можно еще попробовать очистить кеш IDE

Answer (score 0):

Какая версия Go? GO111MODULE используется? думаю проблема в нем.
Скореее всего включен GO111MODULE, а собрать пытаетесь из GOPATH

Go 1.16.3, gotk3 v0.5.3-0.20210601054727, пример собирается корректно

Comment: это не является ответом. когда ваша репутация достигнет 50, вы сможете оставить комментарий. [что почитать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)